# Print Array with JOption Pane

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

Hope someone could help me with this, I'm a fair noob with Java.
My problem is that when I print the array I get some characters and I want to print the number of spots in the array. (Please ignore the non-relevant code, I'm not even near finished)

```
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainClass {

        public static void main (String[] args){


        int arrayIntC, arrayIntE, nOC, nOE;
        char confirmNumbers;

        do{ 
            String numberOfCharacters = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of characters:");
            String numberOfEnemies = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of enemies:");


            nOC = Integer.parseInt(numberOfCharacters);
            nOE = Integer.parseInt(numberOfEnemies);


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of characters: " + nOC, "DnD Organizer", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of enemies: " + nOE, "DnD Organizer", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


            confirmNumbers = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are the numbers correct? (y/n)").charAt(0);


        }while(confirmNumbers != 'y');

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banarne", "DnD Organizer", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        arrayIntC = nOC -1;
        arrayIntE = nOC -1;

        int[] arrayC = {arrayIntC}, arrayE = {arrayIntE};

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Platser i arrayC: ", "DnD Organizer", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        /*for (int i = 0; i <arrayC.length; i++){

            System.out.printf("%5d%8d", i, arrayC[i]);


        }*/

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, arrayC );


    System.exit(0);
    }//main

}//MainClass
```

Comment: Check if the characters correspond to ASCII numbers that could be what you are actually looking for

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a few different problems here.  What is your intent with the following code?

```
int[] arrayC = {arrayIntC}, arrayE = {arrayIntE};
```

If the user enters "10" for the number of characters, `arrayC` will be set to an array with a size of 1 containing an element with a value of 10.

If your intent was to create an empty array of size 10, you'll need to initialize the array like this:

```
int[] arrayC = new int[arrayIntC];
```

If you want to print the size of the array, you can change your code to look like this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, arrayC.length );
```

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation here. arrayC is a reference to type `int[]`. By printing the reference you're printing the "memory address"(in quotes because it's not a real memory address), and not the actual values of anything useful.

Comment: Yeah, actually looking at this a second time, its really unclear what the intent is.  The size of arrayC will always be 1.

Comment: he might want arrayC[0]

Comment: Changed up my answer to better reflect what I think the intent of this code is.